# Color the calender list field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a calender list in sharepoint 2010 and my requirement is
when a user from a particular deparment takes a leave then that users leave will be highlighted by a color(and the department column is  a look up field(i have created a department list and there iam having 2 column department and color))
and how to do this by xsl and also by client side script.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by OOB. Create views for the field or c and do calendar overlays.